# Regex to get string between two smileys

Tags: c#, regex, split

Ive been working the whole day to get a regex that can pick out a string between two smileys. Starting with happy smiley and ending with sad.

The string can look like this from the start:

```
:)2017-11-0707:10:03.4479|1225|INFO|AppLogic.AppLogic.Init|Init()|App|1|:(:)2017-11-0707:10:03.4479|12
```

And I want the result to be:

```
:)2017-11-0707:10:03.4479|1225|INFO|AppLogic.AppLogic.Init|Init()|App|1|:(
```

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a `\` in front of the ( or ) bracket for it to work.

You can use the following regex: `[:\])*_)[:\(]`